# How can i upload images to mail using PHP form

Tags: php, forms, image, upload

How can I upload to send multiple images via PHP form without using SMTP or login to a spesific Email Account?

My code only works with one input of File type and I want to use 4 inputs to be able to show all 4 images in the mail.

When I try to add more than one File input it gets 'Error in Email sending'.

What should i do?

Here is my code:

```
<form action="sendmail.php" method="post" name="mainform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table width="500" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
      <tr>
  <th>Attach Your File</th>
  <td><input name="attachment" type="file"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>Attach Your File</th>
  <td><input name="attachment2" type="file"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>Attach Your File</th>
  <td><input name="attachment3" type="file"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>Attach Your File</th>
  <td><input name="attachment4" type="file"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Send"><input type="reset" name="Reset" value="Reset"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>


<?php

$to = $_POST['toEmail'];
$fromEmail = $_POST['fieldFormEmail']; 
$fromName = $_POST['fieldFormName']; 
$subject = $_POST['fieldSubject']; 
$message = $_POST['fieldDescription'];

/* GET File Variables */ 
$tmpName = $_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name']; 
$fileType = $_FILES['attachment']['type']; 
$fileName = $_FILES['attachment']['name']; 

/* Start of headers */ 
$headers = "From: $fromName"; 

if (file($tmpName)) { 
  /* Reading file ('rb' = read binary)  */
  $file = fopen($tmpName,'rb'); 
  $data = fread($file,filesize($tmpName)); 
  fclose($file); 

  /* a boundary string */
  $randomVal = md5(time()); 
  $mimeBoundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$randomVal}x"; 

  /* Header for File Attachment */
  $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n"; 
  $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" ;
  $headers .= " boundary=\"{$mimeBoundary}\""; 

  /* Multipart Boundary above message */
  $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . 
  "--{$mimeBoundary}\n" . 
  "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . 
  "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . 
  $message . "\n\n"; 

  /* Encoding file data */
  $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data)); 

  /* Adding attchment-file to message*/
  $message .= "--{$mimeBoundary}\n" . 
  "Content-Type: {$fileType};\n" . 
  " name=\"{$fileName}\"\n" .
  "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . 
  $data . "\n\n" . 
  "--{$mimeBoundary}--\n"; 
} 

$flgchk = mail ("$to", "$subject", "$message", "$headers"); 

if($flgchk){
  echo "A email has been sent to: $to";
 }
else{
  echo "Error in Email sending";
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

It's not very well to post a big bunch of code and ask for analyzing it. ;-)

Generally: Try to write the data stream you want to send to a file and then analyze it - manually or with some kind of mail tool (could even be a mail client which issue warnings). Try to construct manually a valid email with multiple attachments and then try to reproduce the format with your code.

In your case: I see an issue which is not directly related to "issue with multiple files" but an issue about the content type (thus I'm not writing a comment but an answer): charset **iso-8859-1** should not be used with "**7bit**" but with "8bit" or "quoted-printable" encoding.

EDIT1: Fix bad english.

EDIT2: Read your code again. I don't see any \r for CRLF line endings.